# show/hide drop down using ajax on shopify product page

Tags: shopify, shopify-storefront-api

Im trying to show and hide a dropdown on my shopify product page if one of the product variants = 9ct Gold.

here is the code I am using so far.  The problem I am having is with the API URL for shopify I assume. I cant work out what URL to use for shopify variants on the frontend.

At the moment nothing is showing and I cant work out why.

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var productId = '{{ product.id }}'; // Access the current product ID with Liquid
    var bandWidthSelect = document.getElementById('band-width');

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'https://mystoreurl.myshopify.com/products/' + productId + '.json');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
          var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
          var variants = response.product.variants;
          var selectedVariant = variants.find(function(variant) {
            return variant.option1 === '9ct Gold';
          });

          if (selectedVariant) {
            var bandWidthOptions = selectedVariant.metafields.custom.band_widths.split(',');

            bandWidthSelect.innerHTML = '<option value="">Select Band Width</option>';
            for (var i = 0; i < bandWidthOptions.length; i++) {
              var option = document.createElement('option');
              option.value = bandWidthOptions[i].trim();
              option.textContent = bandWidthOptions[i].trim();
              bandWidthSelect.appendChild(option);
            }

            bandWidthSelect.style.display = 'block';
          } else {
            bandWidthSelect.style.display = 'none';
          }
        } else {
          console.error('Error fetching product:', xhr.status);
        }
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
  });
</script>
```